# Writing files internally

Tags: android, android-activity

Within my app I am trying to write a file, which I can then internally read from.

Would anyone have an example of how to write files to the installation folders of app?

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to write from `Edittext` into file  and read from file into `Edittext`
set the following permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
 EditText LoadedText;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            LoadedText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.LoadedText);
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            //Get the text file
            File file = new File("/sdcard/RouterSetup.txt");

            //Read text from file
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            }
LoadedText.setText(text.toString());
        }

     public void saveFile() {
             try {

                 File  myFile = new File("/sdcard/RouterSetup.txt");
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                        new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append(LoadedText.getText());
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Done writing SD " + LoadedText.getText() + ".txt",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
```

***getFilesDir() vs Environment.getDataDirectory()*** 
**public File getFilesDir ()**

Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with `openFileOutput(String, int)` are stored.

**public static File getExternalStorageDirectory ()**

Return the primary external storage directory. This directory may not currently be accessible if it has been mounted by the user on their computer, has been removed from the device, or some other problem has happened. You can determine its current state with `getExternalStorageState()`.

If you want to get your application path use `getFilesDir()` which will give you path  `/data/data/your package/files`

You can get the path using the Environment var of your data/package using the

`getExternalFilesDir(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()).getAbsolutePath();` which will return the path from the root directory of your external storage as `/storage/sdcard/Android/data/your pacakge/files/data`

To access the external resources you have to provide the permission of `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Would Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); give the path of the installed application? Do you know what path getFilesDir() would give?

Comment: `the installation folders of app?` What do you mean by that? You cannot write there unless rooted.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is

`String filename = "stuff.xml";`

**READ**

```
FileInputStream stream = ctx.openFileInput(filename);
```

*(and below is a really simple example of parsing that file)*

```
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)); 
String line;
try {
    while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
        ...
        // do something cool
        ...
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("MyApp", "SCREAAAAAM", e);
}
```

**WRITE**

```
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter( ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE) );
outputStreamWriter.write("this is text not xml :(");
```

So the two main things to note are the `openFileInput` and `openFileOutput` methods of `Context` (ie your activity) which take care of the heavy lifting

Answer (score -1):

Which type of files you are talking about ?
For data storage you can use [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).
For media type you can use [media storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
    //here i am downloading file from server and writing

    String download_link = "some server location"; 
                URL url = new URL(download_link);
                 HttpsURLConnection c = null;
                if (url.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals("https")) {
                     trustAllHosts();
                     c = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                     c.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
                }
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();
                String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, "Mobi.apk");
                if(outputFile.exists()){
                    outputFile.delete();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();

you need to add permission in manifest file:    

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: why you are setting solution to download from server he is need to write and read file from installation folders of app ?